# Brilliantretail "Please don't redirect to shopping cart"

Tags: expressionengine

I have a few questions about brilliantretail EE2 addon.

1) Is it possible NOT to redirect customer to shopping cart after clicking :add to cart"?
I have kinda mini cart on the right side. I just want it to update the quantity.

2) How can I have qty input field instead of select field? I would like customer to enter the amount of product they want. I have put input field but it puts only 1 item.

```
{if {type_id} != 6 AND {type_id} != 7}
            <label for="qty"> qty </label>

            <input name="qty" class="qty" type="text" value="1">
```

3) How to disable checkout button if requirements of $39 in shopping cart not met?

**Step 1.**
Create 2 classes for your buttons in CSS: active_checkout and inactive_checkout
(make them diff color if you wish)
**Step 2**
Use this code

```
{if ‘{exp:brilliant_retail:cart_items}’ == ‘0’ OR ‘{exp:brilliant_retail:cart_total}’ <= ‘$39’}
<button class=“inactive_checkout”>Checkout</button>
{if:else}
<button class=“active_checkout”>{exp:brilliant_retail:checkout_buttons}</button>
{/if}
```

**Step 3**
Change $39 to any amount you wish to be minimum!

Comment: Have you tried http://www.brilliantretail.com/support?

Answer (score 9):

1) There are a number of users with BrilliantRetail sites that are using ajax to post the product to the cart via ajax. Here are a couple I can think of off of the top of my head:

sanctionsnow.com

www.boobzie.com

2) To create your own input use:

You need to prefix the name with the {product_id} variable. If the post doesn't contain a properly formatted quantity value it assumes "1".

3) Looks this isn't a question but an answer. You are correct to use the {exp:brilliant_retail:cart_total} tag to evaluate the total value of items in the cart.

I'm surprised by the comment that we 'never answer anything' in our support. We try to respond to all forum posts and we have no unanswered tickets. Please post your support related questions to our forums at http://www.brilliantretail.com/forum

Best, 
David

Comment: Just to add to the point. I will be adding an 'Ajax' parameter and a 'Return' parameter to the next release to give you greater control over how you want to manage your product form post.